# Xcode give error for Flutter Code Module 'Razorpay' was created for incompatible target arm64-apple-ios10.0:/Razorpay.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, razorpay

I am trying to deploy my flutter based code on ios store but when opened code in xcode it gives error :

```
Module 'Razorpay' was created for incompatible target arm64-apple-ios10.0: /Users/amitbansal/AndroidStudioProjects/hilton/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule
```

Steps I tried :

```
$ rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
$ rm -fr ios/Pods
$ rm ios/Podfile
$ flutter clean
$ flutter create ios
$ flutter build ios.
```

but it still give error.
If somebody knows how to solve this please let me know, I am new in flutter programming.
Note : same code is already deployed on play store for android devices without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

try to upgrade dependency in for razorpay in your puspec.yaml file.
also run

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter create ios
pod install
```

in your terminal.